# Missing column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

This is very strange, I have been working on this table(model) in Power BI and one of the columns is Timestamp. I used it as the axis for one visual but now the column is gone and no longer in the columns in the Field section on the right, though the visual is still working fine. What could have happened?

Comment: go to data model and see if the field is marked as hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have accidentally deleted it...

Go to Transform Data to get tot he PowerQuery editor.

Click on the relevant table and then look at the APPLIED STEPS. Click on each one from the bottom up to preview the data at the selected steps to see where it has gone wrong.

Also check your data source - has it disappeared from there maybe?

[image]